# How to handle a gridView's CellMouseClick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Can anybody please tell me if there are any events to handle GridViewCell click? I'm looking for an Event that is similar to *DataGridView.CellMouseClick()*.

It is Needed to register the click event of Dynamic GridView which contains dynamically added Checkboxes. So it's not possible to access the CheckedChanged Event.

Answer (score 0):

Set  `AutoPostback=True` for the dynamic checkbox and handle the `OnCheckedChanged` event.